# how to link userId with post table

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to link userId in user table with each post in post table.

Here is my **Post model**:-

```
const Post = db.define(
"Post",
{
id: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true,
},
title: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
},
userId: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
},
},
);
```

```
User.hasMany(Post, { foreignKey: "userId" });

Post.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "userId" });
```

Here is my **User Model**:-

```
    const User = db.define(
    "User",
    {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    },
    );
```

and here is my **post request**:-

```
     router.post(
      "/",
    [
    upload.array("images", config.get("maxImageCount")),
    imageResize,
    ],
     async (req, res) => {
    const paths = await req.files.map((file) => ({ fileName: file.filename }));
    await Post.create(
      {
        title: req.body.title,
        userId: req.body.userId,
        Post_Images: paths.map((x) => ({ images: x.fileName })),
      },
      { include: [Post_Image] }
    ).then(
      res.status(201).send({
        msg: "upload successful",
      }),
      (validation) => {
        res.status(422).json({
          errors: validation.errors.map((error) => {
            return {
              fieldName: error.path,
              message: error.message,
            };
          }),
        });
      }
    );
     }
     );
```

In my create call I tried using `userId: req.body.userId`, but it does not work it keeps returning userId null.

Comment: Did you look at `req.body.userId`? Is it correct?

Comment: when i do console.log(req.body.userId) i get undefined. i even tried req.userId and req.body.user its not working

Comment: So did you try to output `req.body.userId` or `req.body.user`?

Comment: i tried to output both req.body.userId and req.body.user and both were undefined

Comment: It means you didn't pass userId from a client side. Look at the whole `req.body`. What do see there?

Comment: console.log(req.body) gives me this [Object: null prototype] {title:'test',} with no userId

Comment: in my client side im using data.append("userId",post.user)

Comment: Check how you send userId in a request

Comment: What's the `data`?

Comment: const addPost = (post) =>{ const data=new FormData(); data.append("userId",post.user)};

Comment: Did you use body-parser? Did you check `post.user` on a client?

Comment: yes i am using body-parser on server side

Comment: on client side when i do console.log(post.user) i get undefined

Comment: That's it! Correct this. Nevertheless this does not related to Sequelize at all. Your `create` call seems ok

Comment: so this is to do with client side code then, if it works req.body.userId will display userId in post table in db correct?

Comment: yes, exactly. It will be there